# Attempting to initialize CoreML model results in ambiguous error message

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, coreml

I'm working on a Message Filter Extension for iOS 14.0 involving CoreML. I'm trying to load a mlmodel (`TSF_ML_2 1.mlmodel`) that I generated using Create ML. The model ostensibly works when used in the preview section of Xcode/Create ML, but when the model is initialized programmatically, I get the following error on which I cannot find any information:

> initialization of text classifier model with model data failed

Full traceback:

```
2020-07-05 15:51:07.965420-0400 SpamFilter[36466:3635584] [coreml] MLModelAsset: load failed with error Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "initialization of text classifier model with model data failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=initialization of text classifier model with model data failed}
2020-07-05 15:51:07.967619-0400 SpamFilter[36466:3635584] [coreml] MLModelAsset: modelWithError: load failed with error Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "initialization of text classifier model with model data failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=initialization of text classifier model with model data failed}
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "initialization of text classifier model with model data failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=initialization of text classifier model with model data failed}: file /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpamApp-fqenpxvawdmzkvdmdxjbatoucwji/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SpamApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/SpamFilter.build/DerivedSources/CoreMLGenerated/TSF_ML_2 1/TSF_ML_2 1.swift, line 63
2020-07-05 15:51:07.970910-0400 SpamFilter[36466:3635584] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "initialization of text classifier model with model data failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=initialization of text classifier model with model data failed}: file /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpamApp-fqenpxvawdmzkvdmdxjbatoucwji/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SpamApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/SpamFilter.build/DerivedSources/CoreMLGenerated/TSF_ML_2 1/TSF_ML_2 1.swift, line 63
(lldb)
```

I'm working with Xcode 12.0 beta (12A6159), and generated the mlmodel with the Create ML (Version 1.1 Beta (41)) associated with this Xcode.

Things I've tried:

- Regenerating the mlmodel using various parameters & data. (Principally I am using transfer learning)
- Confirm that the target is correct and mlmodel classes are generated/linked appropriately
- Manually specifying model URL with `contentsOf`
- Compiling `mlmodelc` on the device instead of in Xcode

Here is my initialization logic in `MessageFilterExtension.swift` (breaks @ line 1):

```
let model:TSF_ML_2_1! = TSF_ML_2_1()

guard let spamOutput = try? model.prediction(text: messageBody) else {
    fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
}

print(spamOutput.label)
```

And here is the relevant portion of the autogenerated Swift model class, `TSF_ML_2 1.swift` (error traceback @ line 63):

```
52 class TSF_ML_2_1 {
53     let model: MLModel
54     class var urlOfModelInThisBundle : URL {
55         let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
56         return bundle.url(forResource: "TSF_ML_2 1", withExtension:"mlmodelc")!
57     }
58     init(model: MLModel) {
59         self.model = model
60     }
61     @available(*, deprecated, message: "Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately.")
62     convenience init() {
63         try! self.init(contentsOf: type(of:self).urlOfModelInThisBundle)
64     }
    ...
   }
```

Comment: Might be a beta issue.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm stuck on the same thing with the Message Filter app extension. It keeps returning `initialization of text classifier model with model data failed`. But when loading the model in the main app, there's not issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use this model initialization when you define your `MLModel`:

```
var myModel: Resnet50 = try! Resnet50(configuration: MLModelConfiguration.init())
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ecountered that Code in this way works without any errors.

```
let myModel: modelName = try! modelName(configuration: MLModelConfiguration.init())

guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: myModel.model) else {fatalError()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning Swift, but it looks like they want you to catch both the model init and the prediction. Here is how I would have coded your prediction:

```
do {
    let model = try TSF_ML_2_1(configuration: .init())
    let spamOutput = try model.prediction(text: messageBody)
    // successful code
} catch {
    // failure code
}
```

That seems to work for me.